# Array map function in react for ternary operator

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is my array

```
var CountryList = [{ name: Canada, value: 1 },
    { name: USA, value: 2 }]
```

This is the operation I am using right now

```
var filterStr = nextProps.Country.value == "1" ? 'Canada' : 'USA';
```

Now I want to use the array `CountryList` in the above code using  to check whether Canada or USA is selected. Is it done using **map**?
If it's USA I want to populate States of USA in another Dropdown. If it's Canada Then States of Canada. SO according to the Selection from this array I want to populate the States. I need to check the selected country . ie, I want to get the country name.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
var states = {USA: [{name: 'A', value:1},..],Canada: []} 
var country = CountryList.find(country => country.value == nextProps.Country.value).name;
if (states[county]){
    this.setState({states: states[country], enabledStates: true});
}else{
    this.setState({states: [], enabledStates: false});
}
```

Show the states based on the flag enabledState.

Comment: is it 'nextProps.CountryList.value' because I am using the array CountryList

Answer (score 0):

if you want an array of all countries that have the name USA for exemple, you can use filter like this :

```
CountryList.filter = country => country.value === 1 ;
```

or if want to check if USA for exemple exist in this array, you can use "find"

Answer (score 0):

`map` is not the correct function to use over here.
You should use either `find` or `filter` function.

`let country = CountryList.find((c) => (c.value === 1))
country = country && country.name`